# How to make EditText to show the input letters or strings

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing a weird problem in edittext control of android.

The issue is, when i type anything in softkeyboard. the text is not getting printed in editbox.

Here is the code

```
mEditview.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                           InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                           imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                    }
                }
            });
            mEditview.requestFocus();
```

layout code is added

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/filter_text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="Search"/>
```

Here is what i get as output in emulator. Why  its coming like this? how to fix this problem

[image]

Comment: Add source code for your Layout xml where EditText exists

Comment: @geeknizer, code is added plz help me

Comment: mEditview.setOnFocusChangeListener is not needed Keyboard would popup on device when EditText gains focus. On emulator, it may not since hardware keyboard exists.

Comment: Try a different emulator or an actual device, there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @geeknizer, if i type anything, why text is not getting printed in edit window... I m scared of this strange behaviour..

Comment: Your code works on my emulator (API 8), so try a new emulator, or other API. And as @geeknizer said, the soft keyboard will be shown automatically, if the hardware keyboard is disabled.

Comment: @nistv4n, even its not working in my xperia phone.. How come its working in ur code... why the letter is getting displayed in that transparent screen?, what is it called?.. why it appears any idea?

Comment: Don't you use a custom keyboard, like swype or something else? Or press one of the recommendations above the keyboard. Is it work?